# How could I use batch normalization with tensorflow slim?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I've found a few questions on using batch normalization in TensorFlow, but none of them are about it's wrapper in slim.

I'm trying to use batch normalization to train a MNIST digit classifier. While the training performance is high enough, the validation or test performance is poor.

I built only one graph, and passed `is_training` as a tf.placeholder, just like this (BN is used in every conv and fc layer):

```
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.fully_connected],
                    normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
                    normalizer_params={'is_training': is_training}):
    conv1 = slim.conv2d(x_image, 32, [5, 5], scope='conv1')
    pool1 = slim.max_pool2d(conv1, [2, 2], scope='pool1')
    conv2 = slim.conv2d(pool1, 64, [5, 5], scope='conv2')
    pool2 = slim.max_pool2d(conv2, [2, 2], scope='pool2')
    flatten = slim.flatten(pool2)
    fc = slim.fully_connected(flatten, 1024, scope='fc1')
    drop = slim.dropout(fc, keep_prob=keep_prob)
    logits = slim.fully_connected(drop, 10, activation_fn=None, scope='logits')
```

I also added control dependencies as following:

```
update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
if update_ops:
    updates = tf.group(*update_ops)
    cross_entropy = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies([updates], cross_entropy)
```

For the training phase, I use:

```
sess.run([net['cross_entropy'], net['accuracy']],
                                feed_dict={net['x']: batch_xs,
                                           net['y_']: batch_ys,
                                           net['keep_prob']: 1.0,
                                           net['is_training']: True})
```

For the validation phase, I use:

```
sess.run(net['accuracy'], feed_dict={net['x']: batch_xs,
                                                net['y_']: batch_ys,
                                                net['keep_prob']: 1.0,
                                                net['is_training']: False})
```

For test purpose, I dump the trained model to a checkpoint, then pass `is_training` as False. Again, it's performance is poor.

So what's wrong with it? Is it about the `reuse` parameter? Or I need to maintain `gamma` and `beta` variables in BN layer myself?

For ease of reproducity, this is my code(set `phase` to `train` to train a model and validate, `test` to restore from checkpoint and test):
https://github.com/soloice/mnist-bn/blob/master/mnist_bn.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the problem, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1122#issuecomment-280325584
 for details. Roughly speaking, one need to use `slim.learning.create_train_op` to create train op, and must be patient to wait for moving mean/variance parameters to warm up.